# ¿Se puede responder con otro lenguaje al que el OP pide?

Tags: discusión, respuesta

Me acabo de encontrar con esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/268792/determinar-datetime-para-cada-d%C3%ADa-de-la-semana-con-php) al cuál le he planteado una "solución" (no se si esta del todo clara) que utilice yo hace unos días pero con otro lenguaje.

¿Puedo usar una respuesta planteándole mi código con otro lenguaje? ¿Debería mejor usar un compilador y adjuntarle un enlace como respuesta? ¿O como comentario?

Comment: ¿Cómo se dice "*I don't know*" en Español?: "*Je ne se pais*".

Comment: Alguna vez he respondido en pseudo-código. Tampoco lo vería tan mal si la pregunta y el concepto lo permite.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster "yo no compré pan" (je ne comprend pas) =P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No lo veo viable, pues aunque estarías dando una respuesta el OP deberá *trasladar* tu solución al lenguaje sobre el cual el esta trabajando, que en este caso es PHP.

Lo anterior pudiera derivar en una nueva pregunta, de tipo:

> Tengo el siguiente código en [inserte lenguaje aquí], ¿cómo logro lo mismo en PHP?

Considero que lo mejor aquí es aportar una solución que este basada en la herramienta que dicha persona esta usando, recordando que la solución que demos a las preguntas de la plataforma no solo le deben servir a quien pregunta sino que además le deben servir a futuros usuarios.

Comment: Imaginemos la pregunta como ubico el maximo en un array en delphi.. y la respuesta es en C# usas con linq array.max.... contestar en otro lenguaje.. no esta bien.

Answer (score 8):

Depende. Si la pregunta trata sobre un algoritmo que podría implementarse con cualquier otro lenguaje (es decir no es algo tipo "¿Cómo funcionan los genéricos en C#?") y crees que puedes aportar una solución al problema planteado por el OP pero no dominas el lenguaje original de la pregunta, no veo por qué no se puede responder usando otro lenguaje - o aún mejor, pseudocódigo. Lo importante es dejar el concepto bien explicado, de forma que el OP pueda entenderlo e implementarlo en su lenguaje - ¡eso es ciertamente (mucho) mejor que nada y una buena oportunidad de aprendizaje!

Comment: Muy de acuerdo. Creo que en este caso específico no aplicaba, pero muchas veces una estructura de pseudocódigo es más útil que el código en sí.

Comment: Como señala fedorqui es mejor el pseudocódigo o una buena explicación debido a que la implementación de un algoritmo se basa en las características particulares del lenguaje de programación. Por ejemplo muchas la forma de implementar un algoritmo conceptualmente es distinto debido a que el programador aprovecha las ventajas del lenguaje.

Answer (score 3):

Depende del contexto.

Si se trata únicamente de sabor sintáctico es perfectamente correcto, si el lenguaje mismo tiene cambios en el aspecto semántico entonces no; en otras palabras, si tiene significado equivalente esta bien, si cambia todo el sentido entonces no.

Me refiero con esto a que, muchas veces las librerías son tan famosas que tienen su **traducción en varios lenguajes de programación** siend el código una transformación directa a la que solamente le aplicaron las convenciones de ese otro lenguaje.

Tal caso llega a suceder por ejemplo entre programadores de [c#](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) y [java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), donde la capitalización de los métodos es exactamente opuesta.

Otro caso válido es cuando se trata de una **familia de lenguajes**, como es el caso de [.net](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) donde una respuesta en [vb.net](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net) puede servirle a alguien que use [c3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c3), o lenguajes de la [jvm](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jvm), donde una respuesta en [java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), [jython](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jython) o [jruby](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jruby) pueda servirle a alguien que programa en [kotlin](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlin).

Un ejemplo más de familias de lenguajes es para el caso del motor de juegos [unity3d](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d), en que muchas veces es fácil portar las soluciones entre [boo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boo) (Python), [unityscript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unityscript) ( una especie de javascript tipeado ) y C#.

Para tu caso en particular, se trata de dos lenguajes de la **familia de lenguajes web**, y ciertamente se puede hacer lo mismo en ambos en este caso, lo que deberías de pedirle aclaración es acerca de si se necesita una solución que funcione en el servidor o en el cliente, ya que PHP puede generar código de ambos y js normalmente se relega al cliente (si no se usa un stack node).

Yo normalmente le respondería "En javascript se hace así, las funciones equivalentes de PHP son tales. En caso de ser complejo, el pseudocódigo es tal y creo que te podría ayudar a resolver tu problema por esto".
De esta manera ayudas, puedes ser recompensado con puntos de reputacion por ello, y abres la posibilidad para que un experto que llegue después complemente tu respuesta con la sintaxis correcta.

Recuerda que nuestro principal objetivo no debe ser resolver el problema de alguien sino beneficiar a la comunidad con conocimiento generado mediante la inteligencia colectiva.

Comment: Muy bueno el último párrafo!!